# Which part of blue fish is not edible?

Tags: food-safety, fish

I bought a blue fish caught in Maryland. Can I eat the entire fish, or are there some parts of it which are not edible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Fishing Tips: How to Catch, Prepare, and Cook Bluefish](http://habee.hubpages.com/hub/Fishing-Tips-How-to-Catch-Prepare-and-Cook-Bluefish):

> When you clean the fish, remove the skin and any dark-colored flesh. This part of the fish is especially strong tasting and somewhat oily.
>   Check out these fish recipes to learn to cook bluefish.

Also see [How Can You Cook Bluefish To Make It Taste Good](http://www.fishingtalks.com/how-can-you-cook-bluefish-to-make-it-taste-good-2910411.html) for advices on improving the flavor (e.g. soak it in milk).